# Best approach to automatic flip of database from Java app in AWS platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

We have an application ( Java Spring boot ) deployed in AWS EKS cluster over EC2 node. Auto scale is enabled in EKS cluster and based on the loads  in EC2 nodes will be created in different AZ.  We are planning to create two Oracle DB ( On-Prem, One is primary and other is secondary ) servers and golden gate will replicate data between DBs. Application will connect DB using JDBC connection string. What is the best way to failover from primary to secondary automatically without impacting the Java Spring boot app in case primary DB is down? Should we maintain two versions of a Java app with two different DB connection strings?

Planning to use two different version of Java app with different DB string. But looking best approach to achieve the end results.